# Reemplazar jQuery ajax con una petición $http de Angular en angular.config()

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

Estoy cargando estados para el $stateProvider desde un archivo .json, todo funciona, pero tal vez hay una mejor manera de hacerlo sin la llamada ajax de jQuery:

config.js

```
var STATES_FILE = '../config/states.json';
var statesObj,
  states;

function configState($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider, $compileProvider) {

   function resolveUrl(path){
       var loadUrl = { // Any property in resolve should return a promise and is executed before the view is loaded
           loadModule: ['$ocLazyLoad', function($ocLazyLoad) {
               // you can lazy load files for an existing module
               return $ocLazyLoad.load(path);
           }]
       };
       return loadUrl;
   }

    // Optimize load start with remove binding information inside the DOM element
    $compileProvider.debugInfoEnabled(true);

    // Set default state
    $urlRouterProvider.otherwise("/dashboard");

   // Get states from configuration file
    states = $.ajax({
      type: 'GET', 
      url: STATES_FILE, 
      async: false
    })
    .responseText;

    statesObj = eval("(" + states + ")")

    // Load states from states configuration
    for(var prop in statesObj){
      $stateProvider.state(prop, statesObj[prop]);
    }    

  }

angular
  .module('homer')
  .config(configState)
  .run(function($rootScope, $state) {
      $rootScope.$state = $state;
  });
```

Y mi archivo states.json:

```
{
    "dashboard": {
        "name": "dashboard",
        "url": "/dashboard",
        "templateUrl": "./views/dashboard.html",
        "data": {
            "pageTitle": "Dashboard"
        }
    },
    "users": {
        "name": "users",
        "url": "/users",
        "controller": "usersCtrl",
        "templateUrl": "/users/views/users.html",
        "resolve": "resolveUrl('/users/app/js/compiled/users_app.js')"
    },
    "invoices": {
        "name": "invoices",
        "url": "/invoices",
        "controller": "invoicesCtrl",
        "templateUrl": "/invoices/views/invoices.html",
        "resolve": "resolveUrl('/invoices/app/js/compiled/invoices_app.js')"
    },
    "invoices.upload": {
        "name": "invoices.upload",
        "url": "/upload",
        "controller": "invoicesCtrl",
        "templateUrl": "/invoices/views/invoices.html",
        "resolve": "resolveUrl('/invoices/app/js/compiled/invoices_app.js')"
    },
    "reports": {
        "name": "reports",
        "url": "/reports",
        "templateUrl": "./views/reports.html",
        "data": {
            "pageTitle": "Reports"
        }
    }
}
```

Por lo que he leído es mejor utilizar las funciones $q y $http de Angular. Así que traté de resolverlo con:

```
function resolveStates($http, $q) {

    var deferred = $q.defer();

    $http({
      method:'GET',
      url: STATES_FILE
    }).success(function (data) {
      deferred.resolve(data);
    });

    return deferred.promise;

  }
```

Pero me da este error, `Uncaught Error: [$injector:modulerr]`

Comment: para tener un mensaje de error detallado, tienes que utilizar la version **NO** minificada de angularjs.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Puedes hacer solo la llamada `get` haciendo uso del servicio `$http` de angular.

Lo que te aconsejo es que hagas un controlador mas o menos como lo siguiente:

```
angular.module("app")
.controller("ctrlMain", [ '$scope','$http', function($scope, $http) {
    $http({
        method: 'GET',
        url: STATES_FILE
    }).then(function successCallback(response) {
        console.log("Success", response)
    }, function errorCallback(response) {
        console.log("Error",response);
    }); 
}])
```

y dentro del controlador hagas tu petición.

Para mas información del servicio `$http` puedes chequear su [documentación](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http)

Comment: Me parece una buena solución. ¿Cómo debería hacer el llamado desde mi archivo `config.js` a mi controlador? Por ejemplo si lo agrego como una función no anónima en el controlador. Se puede crear algo como: `$scope.getStates = function()...

Comment: Si, y dentro de la función `$scope.getStates` haces la petición y al final o dentro del `success` colocas un `return` para que te regrese el `respose` de la petición al mandar llamar la función.

Comment: Ya agregué la función $scope.getStates en mi archivo `main.js` para probarla usé un botón  `<button ng-click="getStates()">States</button>` y funcionó, pero cómo puedo accederla desde mi archivo `config.js`? Intenté haciendo un llamado simple con `var test = getStates()` pero no funciona. Gracias.

Comment: Lo que puedes hacer es hacer un `factory` que haga la petición `getStates`, entonces ese `factory`lo importas como servicio en cada uno de tus controladores lo que conlleva que tu archivo `config.js` lo convirtieras en un `controller`,una vez hecho eso podrás mandar llamar la función `getStates` desde cualquier controlador que tenga el servicio el servicio agregado.

Answer (score 0):

Puedes utilizar un factory de angular, a mí me ha servido. Lo traes en el controlador como una promise.

Por ejemplo, para traerte la data desde tu archivo states.json

**FACTORY:**

```js
tumodulo.factory('globalFactory', function($rootScope, $http){

  var globalFactory = {};

  globalFactory.getUrl = function(){
    return $http.get('states.json');
  };

  return globalFactory;

});
```

**CONTROLADOR:**

```js
tumodulo.controller("tucontrolador", tucontrolador);

function tucontrolador($http, globalFactory){

  //Aquí va la promise
  globalFactory.getUrl().then(function(response){
  
    var urlX = response.data;
    
    //Una variable más para "deserializar" ese JSON
    var deserializar = angular.fromJson(urlX);
    
    //Aqui capturas que URL necesitas
    var urlQueNecesitas = deserializar[el indice de tu arreglo];
     
    
  });

}
```